# $\|\nabla f\|_p\leq C (\|\nabla \times f \|_p +\|\nabla \cdot f\|_p)$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R^3}\to \mathbb{R^3}$ have compact support.
The identity
$$
-\Delta = \nabla\times\nabla \times - \nabla \nabla \cdot,
$$
and two integration by parts shows that
$$
\|\nabla f\|_2 = \|\nabla \times f \|_2 +\|\nabla \cdot f\|_2.
$$

More generally, does an equality of the form

$$
\|\nabla f\|_p\leq C (\|\nabla \times f \|_p +\|\nabla \cdot f\|_p)
$$

hold for some constant $C$ independent of $f$?